# How can i color my text?

Tags: java

i have written a program that will print the text "My name is salman" but i want color this text how to do this since i am a beginner to java ???

this what i have done :

```
public class Main extends JPanel {  
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){    
        Font font = new Font("Serif",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,45);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString("My name is salman", 99, 99);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
       JFrame f = new JFrame();
       f.getContentPane().add(new Main());
       f.setVisible(true);
       f.setSize(700, 600);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try moving the call to `g.setColor(Color.red);` *before* you call `g.drawString`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main extends JPanel {  
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){    
        Font font = new Font("Serif",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,45);
        g.setFont(font); // first set font
        g.setColor(Color.red); // and color
        g.drawString("My name is salman", 99, 99); // and after that draw a sting
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
       JFrame f = new JFrame();
       f.getContentPane().add(new Main());
       f.setVisible(true);
       f.setSize(700, 600);
    }
}
```

You have to change the color first before changing the font color or else it will not work ..

Answer (score 1):

call `drawString` method after `setFont` and `setColor` mothod.

Answer (score 1):

You should just change to order like this:

```
  Font font = new Font("Serif",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,45);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawString("My name is salman", 99, 99);
```

1- Set the font.
2- set the color.
3- Draw the string.